# pass values from the view to the controller ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, parameters, controller

This is my controller:

```
def addcar
    @car = Car.new(params[:car])    
    render :action => "list"  
end
```

this is my view:

```
<%(@allcars).each do |cell|%>
    <p><%= link_to cell.to_s, :controller => "car", :action => "addcar", :car => cell.to_s %></p>
<%end %>
```

In the `link_to` statement I want to pass `cell.to_s` to the controller. How can I do that please? The `cell.to_s` is just a string but I want it to be the name of the car object (`car.Name`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Car.new(params[:car])` expects `params[:car]` to be a Hash (`{:foo => "bar"}`). So change your code:

```
<% @allcars.each do |cell| %>
  <p>
    <%= link_to cell.to_s,
          :controller => "car",
          :action => "addcar",
          :car => { :name => cell.to_s } %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```