# Double namespaced routing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, controller, routes

I'm trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816801/pass-values-from-the-view-to-the-controller-ruby-on-rails) example.
I've created an action in my controller:

```
  def distribute_resume
    Rails.logger.info(distribution_id.to_s)
    PartnerNotifier.distribute_resume(distribution_id)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully distributed resume"
    redirect_to admin_distributions_workflows_path
  end
```

and I created a route in my `config/routes.rb' file:

```
  namespace :admin do
    namespace :distributions do
      resources :workflows do
        collection do
          post :edit_multiple
          put :update_multiple
          post :distribute_resume
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I also tried moving the route to the action outside of the collection block like this:

```
  namespace :admin do
    namespace :distributions do
      resources :workflows do
        post :distribute_resume
        collection do
          post :edit_multiple
          put :update_multiple
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

But i'm getting this error in both cases:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"admin/distributions/workflows_controller", :distribution_id=>123, :action=>"distribute_resume", :method=>:post}
```

I'm too green to figure this out.

update:

ah yes, need to remember to check `rake routes` more often. I do see this:

```
admin_distributions_workflow_distribute_resume POST   /admin/distributions/workflows/:workflow_id/distribute_resume(.:format) {:action=>"distribute_resume", :controller=>"admin/distributions/workflows"}
```

so I changed my view:

```
      <%=link_to "Send this resume to #{distribution.matching_profile.partner.email}",
            :controller => "workflows", <-- instead of "workflows_controller"
            :action => "distribute_resume",
            :distribution_id => distribution.id,
            :method => :post%>
```

but i'm still getting a similar error message:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"admin/distributions/workflows", :distribution_id=>121, :action=>"distribute_resume", :method=>:post}
```

Comment: What do you get when you type `rake routes` at the console?

Comment: added an update at the bottom of OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

**First**

You are not passing in `:workflow_id` during your POST request.  If you look at your `rake routes` results, you'll see it is necessary:

```
/admin/distributions/workflows/:workflow_id/distribute_resume(.:format)
```

**Second**

When you namespace the routes like that, you are telling it that you have also reflected that namespacing within the Controller as well.

So

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :distributions do
    resources :workflows do
    end
  end
end
```

Means that you would need to do this in your controller:

```
class Admin::Distributions::WorkflowsController < ApplicationController
  # controller code goes here
end
```

If you'd rather not namespace your controllers like that, then you need to switch up your routing syntax to instead be:

```
scope "/admin" do
  scope "/distributions" do
    resources :workflows do
    end
  end
end
```

which will still give you the same routing scheme but will not force you to do the controller module prefixes like before.  Keep in mind if you switch to the scoped method, your path names will change so run `rake routes` to get the new ones.

More info:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

---

Update:

I think you're making this a little more complicated then it needs to be.  Your `link_to` can be simplified to this:

```
<% =link_to "Send this resume to #{distribution.matching_profile.partner.email}",
            admin_distributions_workflow_distribute_resume_path(distribution.id),
            :remote => true,
            :method => :post %>
```

Comment: that's almost exactly what I have for my controller: `class Admin::Distributions::WorkflowsController < Admin::BaseController`

Comment: Updated answer, you're also not passing in the `:workflow_id` during the POST request

Comment: so, i changed my link_to in my view to this: `
          <%=link_to "Send this resume to #{distribution.matching_profile.partner.email}",
                :controller => "workflows",
                :action => "distribute_resume",
                :workflow_id => distribution.id %>` but I'm now getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'workflow_id' for #<Admin::Distributions::WorkflowsController:0x139758e30>`

Comment: is there something I need to do to let my controller know about 'workflow_id'?

Comment: See the bottom of my post for how to simplify your `link_to`.  You should just be passing `distribution.id` into the path helper that rails generates for you.

Comment: ok, thanks. that feels more like what I need. But what should the corresponding route be? i'm now getting this error: `No route matches [GET] "/admin/distributions/workflows/121/distribute_resume"`. It's unclear to me why it's trying to do a get request.

Comment: Do you have the Rails UJS gem (or javascript) installed?  I posted it on your question yesterday for the jQuery checkbox answer.  It allows Rails to see the `data-method` attribute on your anchor link and ensure that the proper methods (POST, PUT, etc) are being sent to the controller

Comment: it looks like no, ujs is not installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6045/discussion-between-ramy-and-iwasrobbed)

Comment: Since you are doing a POST via a `link_to` (HTML anchor) tag, you need that Rails UJS installed or else it will default to a GET request.  If you have it installed properly, the Rails UJS javascript will capture the link click and send it as a POST request via jQuery's `$.ajax` method instead

Answer (score 1):

You've got your `distribute_resume` action as a member, not a collection, action. Is this what you intended? You're calling it as if it was a collection action.

So, either move your route declaration into the `collection do` portion (if it's supposed to be a collection action), or pass in a workflow ID in your redirect.

Either way you're also going to have to rename your redirect path, because it doesn't actually call the `distribute_resume` action, it calls the index action.

You currently have:

```
redirect_to admin_distributions_workflows_path
```

And this will need to be renamed to something along the lines of either (collection version):

```
redirect_to admin_distributions_workflows_distribute_resume_path
```

or (member version):

```
redirect_to admin_distributions_workflows_distribute_resume_path(@some_workflow_or_distribution_object)
```

Comment: where does my redirect path need to be renamed? I don't quite follow you there.

Comment: Updated my answer. You're not including the name of the action in your path, so Rails has not idea what you're talking about.

Comment: hmm....something else is going on, i'm now getting this error `undefined local variable or method 'workflow_id' for #<Admin::Distributions::WorkflowsController:0x139c15f68>` regardless of what my "redirect_to" is

Comment: You're missing some really basic things here. It might be easier if you jump into chat, and we can discuss it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6044/double-namespaced-routing-issues?tab=general#

Comment: @Normalicity I think Ramy is just redirecting to the `index` action after the resume is successfully emailed out in the `distribute_resume` action, so the way it is in the OP would be correct.  Maybe I am misunderstanding the intention though.